# Get Video Source URL with Graph API Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get Video source URL with Graph API by using Javascript SDK

This is what i have built using default code for video object

```
function getVideo(id) {
var vid = id;
FB.api(
"video/{vid}",
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    var v = "source": source;
    alert(v);
  }
}
);
}
```

Comment: And what isn't working, exactly?

Comment: What does response contain?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the endpoint

```
/{video_id}
```

instead of

```
/video/{video_id}
```

This is clearly stated in the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/video/

You code needs to be

```
function getVideo(id) {
    FB.api("/"+id, function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @ZeroOne what is the alternate in latest API ?

Answer (score 0):

you can request one more extra field param by API

> $pageid = "YOURPAGENAME";
>
> $facebook->api("/" . $pageid . "/feed?fields=location&locale=en_GB&fields=type,message,id,story,link,created_time,attachments,source,name,picture,object_id,place&limit=20");

source => will return url mp4 video post

And make sure you will see the type in attachment array,

**[type] => video_inline / video_share_youtube**

you will get both type of video url like:

https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/xxxxxxx8431328184267440128_n.mp4

https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxx?autoplay=1